# Visual Studio 2022 version 17.4.1 does not honor tabs configuration when adding new items to the project

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm having a strange issue with **Visual Studio 2022 version 17.4.1**.

Basically it seems that, starting from this version, Visual Studio 2022 does **not** honor the tabs configuration for the C# language when adding new items to the project via the *Add -> New Item* wizard.

My configuration for the text editor tabs for the C# language (*Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> C# -> Tabs*) are the followings:

- Indenting: Smart
- Tab Size: 2
- Indent Size: 2
- Insert Spaces selected

With the previous versions of Visual Studio 2022 when a new class was added to the project these settings were honored as expected. The indentation used for the C# code in the newly generated class was 2 spaces, as expected given these settings.

Starting from version **17.4.1** I noticed that these settings are always ignored when a new class is added to the project via the *Add -> Class* or the *Add -> New Item* wizard.**In the newly added class, the indentation used is always 4 spaces instead of the expected 2 spaces**. So, my configuration is **not** being honored.

Is this an expected behavior ?
Is there a known workaround for this ?

This is quite annoying because I have to reformat each time I add a new class to the project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After my testing, this is indeed a bug.

I suggest you post this to the [dc forums](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/VisualStudio?q=%5BVisual+Studio+2022+version+17.4.1%5D) and attach the relevant link to the question.

Update:

A fix for this issue has been internally implemented and is being prepared for [release.](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/VS-2022-174:-C-editor-always-uses-Smar/10195742)

Answer (score 0):

This Visual Studio bug has been fixed in Visual Studio 2022 version `17.4.2`.

See [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/VS-2022-174:-C-editor-always-uses-Smar/10195742#T-N10216450) for details.

Comment: I have 17.6 and still not working for aspx files